# Numeric data collection from an mp3 in python

Tags: python, mp3, numeric, graphical-programming

Anyone know how I can plot numeric data from an mp3 in real time?

For example the script plays a mp3 and as its playing prints 3 sets of numeric data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Veusz](http://home.gna.org/veusz/) python package that supports realtime plotting of data.